# Find value of angle B

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry, angle

[image]

Can't get around this one at first I thought the answer was small b

Comment: I think you can solve this problem by yourself.

Comment: Maybe we can guide you if you show us what you tried

Comment: thanks i get it now i forgot to let the angled at c

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x$ the unknown angle, then $$2x+a=180^{\circ}$$

Answer (score 1):

The sum of angles in a triangle is equal to $180^{\circ}$. So since $A=a$, and $B=C$, then $$B=C=\frac{180^{\circ}-a}{2}$$